# atoi() not working with char array

Tags: c, atoi

I am learning C and I am trying to find how to much things with a database that I have made with char arrays.

I know atoi works with strings, but I cannot understand the difference between string and char array declaration (i understand strings have also a char with '/0').

It creates a warning when compiling 
`[Warning] initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast` at the line `int w = LoggersID[j];`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    // Logger ID Database
    char LoggersID[50][2];
    strcpy(LoggersID[1], "A");
    strcpy(LoggersID[2], "B");
    strcpy(LoggersID[3], "C");
    strcpy(LoggersID[4], "D");
    strcpy(LoggersID[5], "E");
    strcpy(LoggersID[6], "F");
    strcpy(LoggersID[7], "G");
    strcpy(LoggersID[8], "H");
    strcpy(LoggersID[9], "I");
    strcpy(LoggersID[10], "J");
    strcpy(LoggersID[11], "K");
    strcpy(LoggersID[12], "L");
    strcpy(LoggersID[13], "M");
    strcpy(LoggersID[14], "N");
    strcpy(LoggersID[15], "O");
    strcpy(LoggersID[16], "P");
    strcpy(LoggersID[17], "Q");
    strcpy(LoggersID[18], "R");
    strcpy(LoggersID[19], "S");
    strcpy(LoggersID[10], "T");
    strcpy(LoggersID[21], "1");
    strcpy(LoggersID[22], "2");
    strcpy(LoggersID[23], "3");
    strcpy(LoggersID[24], "4");
    strcpy(LoggersID[25], "5");
    strcpy(LoggersID[26], "6");
    strcpy(LoggersID[27], "7");
    strcpy(LoggersID[28], "8");
    strcpy(LoggersID[29], "9");
    strcpy(LoggersID[30], "10");


    printf("Lets start!\n");


    for (int i = 65; i < 86; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 31; j++)
        {
            int w = atoi(LoggersID[j]);
            if (w == i)
            {
                printf("\nYou matched %s with %d", LoggersID[j], i);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 31; j++)
        {
            int w = LoggersID[j];
            if (w == i)
            {
                printf("\nYou matched %s with %d", LoggersID[j], i);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nProgram finished!");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it I get

```
Lets start!

Program finished!
```

instead of matching!

Comment: `strcpy(LoggersID[30], "10");` might not be null-terminated

Comment: `int w = LoggersID[j];` --> `int w = atoi(LoggersID[j]);` ?

Comment: `int w = atoi(LoggersID[j])` tries to convert the string to a number, what you seem to want is `int w = LoggersID[j][0]` to compare the ascii code

Comment: Note: arrays in C start at index 0.

Comment: `strcpy(LoggersID[10], "T");` -> `strcpy(LoggersID[20], "T");`?

Comment: Your code has several problems, but it's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: @Ctx, C does not require the execution character set to be ASCII, so the value of a `char` is not necessarily an *ascii* code.  It might, for example, be an EBCDIC code.

Comment: Among possibly other problems: `strcpy(LoggersID[30], "10");` you copy 3 chars in a 2 char buffer. You probably need `char LoggersID[50][2];` -> `char LoggersID[50][3];`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger While your comment undoubtedly is of high theoretical value, the for loop `for (int i = 65; i < 86; i++)` quite clearly suggests that the OP's platform indeed uses ASCII code as execution character set.

Comment: I have corrected all these now I am getting:

    [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast

and

[Note] expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'

and the program crashes after Lets start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some problems:

- arrays are 0 based in C: the first element is at offset 0.
- the array elements should have at least 3 characters to accommodate for the null terminator for strings of 2 characters such as `"10"`.
- you could use an initializer for the array instead of tediously initializing the elements with `strcpy()`.
- converting the array elements from a string to a numeric value is done either by calling `atoi()` or `strtol()` to convert the string encoded as digits, or by reading the value of the first character with `int w = LoggersId[i][0];`. Converting the address of the element to an `int` is meaningless. The compiler issues a warning:

  ```
  [Warning] initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
      at the line int w = LoggersID[j];
  ```

  Such warnings indicate programming errors and should be considered fatal. you can configure the compiler to help you avoid such mistakes with extra options on the command line, such as `gcc -Wall -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Werror`.

Here is a modified version where you will see the matches for the 2 approaches:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    // Logger ID Database
    char LoggersID[30][3] = {
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
    };

    printf("Lets start!\n");
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
            int w = atoi(LoggersID[j]);
            if (w == i) {
                printf("You matched LoggersID[%d] = \"%s\" with %d\n",
                       j, LoggersID[j], i);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 65; i < 85; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
            int w = LoggersID[j][0];
            if (w == i) {
                printf("You matched LoggersID[%d] = \"%s\" with %d (%c)\n",
                       j, LoggersID[j], i, i);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nProgram finished!");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 issues:

---

Replace `char LoggersID[50][2];` with `char LoggersID[50][3];`

Following line copies 3 chars into a 2 char buffer. The string literal `"10"` takes up 3 chars because of the `NUL` Terminator.

```
strcpy(LoggersID[30], "10");
```

---

Replace `int w = LoggersID[j];` with `int w = atoi(LoggersID[j]);`.

`LoggersID[j]` is a `char*` (pointer to `char`) and not an `int`, therefore you need to convert the string to an `int` using the [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) function.

That's why you get the warning `initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast at the line int w = LoggersID[j]`. This warning is actually most of the time an error.

---

You certainly have a typo here:

Replace `strcpy(LoggersID[10], "T");` by `strcpy(LoggersID[20], "T");`

---

By the way the 30 strcpy lines could be replaced by about 6 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi()` works only for numbers in string like this `"123"`. It will return integer value for this string. As soon as it detects any character other than 0-9, it terminates the process. So in loop, you are not checking for values 1 to 10.

```
  int w = atoi(LoggersID[j]);
        if (w == i)
```

So it is not printing anything. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to print the ASCII for characters or strings?

Comment: yes, implement your own atoi() for specific need.                                           `int atoii(const char *arr)
{
 return arr[0];
}   `                                                                                                          
  This is a reference, written only for 1 character in array, according to your example and need.